# AWS DynamoDB CLI command not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I am unable to execute the put-item command via the command line - sample below.

```
C:\Users\Ishtiaque>aws dynamodb put-item --table-name weatherstationdata --item '{"stationid":{"S":"000001"},"dateandtime" : {"S": "2015/12/25 00:00"},"temperature": {"N" : "0"}}' --profile LOAdmin


Unknown options: {S:, 2015/12/25 00:00},temperature:, {N, :, 0}}', :
```

I have also tried the "\" switch e.g.:

```
C:\Users\Ishtiaque>aws dynamodb put-item --table-name weatherstationdata --item '{\"\stationid":{\"\S":\"\000001"},"dateandtime" : {\"\S": \"\2015/12/25 00:00"},\"\temperature": {\"\N" : \"\0"}}' --profile LOAdmin
```

But still unsuccessful.

I think it is something related to the "" sign but not sure how else resolve.

I can crate item from the console and when use the 'get-item' command, I face a similar error.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression looks ok but if you have complex JSon you can create a new JSon file file.json

```
{
    "dateandtime": {
        "S": "2015/12/25 00:00"
    },
    "stationid": {
        "S": "000001"
    },
    "temperature": {
        "N": "0"
    }
}
```

and then pass it as expression to your command

```
aws dynamodb put-item --table-name weatherstationdata \
    --item file://item.json --profile LOAdmin
```

You should make sure not to include space after the key in Json so something like this would work in CLI

```
aws dynamodb put-item --table-name weatherstationdata --item '{"stationid": {"S": "000001"},"dateandtime": {"S": "2015/12/25 00:00"},"temperature": {"N": "0"}}' --profile LOAdmin
```

Comment: good, please make sure to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it should work if you don't add space right after the key